# Firebase error: unsupported browser while running Jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, jestjs

I have a React.js web app that uses Firebase. I'm now trying to write some integration test using the Jest framework but I'm unable to. When I try to run a test I get the following error:

> FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)

I have attached a screenshot below of my console output:

[image]

In my `login.test.js` file I'm not doing anything besides mounting a page:

```
it('should render', () => {
    const div = mount(<Login />);

    expect(1).toEqual(1)
});
```

I did research on my problem and it was mentioned a couple of times that some people had success overcoming this error by adding the `--browser` tag to the `test` script in the `package.json` like so:

```
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --browser",
```

But I tried and it did not resolve my issue.

EDIT:

[On this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FrenchMajesty/079squ8k/) is the code the `Login` page however all it does that's relevant to this test is use firebase functions to authenticate.

[On this other jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FrenchMajesty/4vm6jhn9/) is the code of `src/config/firebase.js`.

Comment: Could you please share your `Login` component source?

Comment: @OleksandrKovpashko I've updated my post to include the code of the component.